# why does django not combine makemigrations and migrate commands?

Tags: django

I can think of three reasons why:

1. providing users with the flexibility on "when" to commit model changes
2. debugging modularity
3. perhaps resource consumption in larger
   databases

However, it does seem that migrate always follows shortly after migration (tutorials/youtube videos). 
so is there a philosophy behind this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse there are some reasons.

First of all, 'makemigrations' doesn't touch real DB, it just tells django how models(db scheme) have changed so you can see what's going on when you do 'migrate'.

and this makes django more safe.

This also provides to make default options for new fields or db changes..

Other reason is 'revert'.
If you want to roll-back db scehme with specific migrations, you can just tell django to roll back to specific migration file.

Another reason is 'reusable-app' principle.
If you create app with django and it could be reusable with no-db-interaction. It means if you deploy your app(or project, too!) to another project or server, it just needs 'migrations' files not real db.

Comment: ah i see. thanks very much for explaining that. super appreciated! i thought it would have been easy to write a script to combine both actions and seems like it would have been part of the "batteries included" philosophy